# Javascript Move IMG Element Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

Having trouble dynamically moving an img element in between some content.

BEFORE:

```html
    <img id="moveme" class="product__image lazyload-fade lazyautosizes lazyloaded"src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2997/4910/files/blackjacket_overlay.png?9630" style="
    position: absolute;
">
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" style="width: 447px;" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10"><div><a class="fancybox" href="" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"></div>

  <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide11" style="width: 447px;" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control11"><div><a class="fancybox" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2997/4910/files/blackjacket_overlay.png?9630" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
        <div class="product-main-image selected" data-image-id="12046975205420" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
            <img id="3971000074284" class="product__image lazyload-fade lazyautosizes lazyloaded" >
    </div>
```

AFTER:

```html
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" style="width: 447px;" tabindex="-1" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10"><div><a class="fancybox" href="" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"></div>

  <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide11" style="width: 447px;" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control11"><div><a class="fancybox" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2997/4910/files/blackjacket_overlay.png?9630" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
        <div class="product-main-image selected" data-image-id="12046975205420" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
          <!-- I WANT TO DYNAMICALLY PUT THE FOLLOWING ONE IMG ELEMENT HERE USING JAVASCRIPT -->
    <img id="moveme" class="product__image lazyload-fade lazyautosizes lazyloaded"src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2997/4910/files/blackjacket_overlay.png?9630" style="
    position: absolute;
">
            <img id="3971000074284" class="product__image lazyload-fade lazyautosizes lazyloaded" >
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use insertBefore https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

you could create the new image with createElement, add the attributes with setAttribute, that is your new node

```
const newImage = document.createElement('img');
newImage.className = 'product__image lazyload-fade lazyautosizes lazyloaded';
newImage.setAttribute('id', 'moveme');
newImage.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2997/4910/files/blackjacket_overlay.png?9630');
newImage.style.position = 'absolute';
const parent = document.querySelector('div[data-image-id="12046975205420"]');
const refNode = document.querySelector('#3971000074284');
parent.insertBefore(newImage, refNode);
```

select the existing image, that is the reference node, then
select the container div, that is the parent node

`parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`

Comment: possible to use other querySelectors?

Comment: @Lake what do you mean? like getElementByID, etc.? yes, select however you want

Comment: Tested , didn't work. 
Trying to get it to work here:
https://creatortoronto.com/collections/eric-lee/products/goodnight#content

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Comment: @Lake that is saying that the referenceNode isn't a child of the parentNode.  I can't quite tell from the code you posted what the DOM structure is but the ref node and the new node need to have the same parent to use insertBefore.  If they don't maybe appendChild would work to insert the image as the last child of its parent.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  var parent = document.querySelector('div[data-image-id="12046975205420"] img');

  $( "#moveme" ).insertBefore( parent );

     });

This worked! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: why doesn't this work?
  var parent = document.querySelector('div[data-slick-index="1"] div a.fancybox div.product-main-image img');

Comment: @Lake be sure to check out the warning in this section:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore#Syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197804/discussion-between-james-south-and-lake).